# Python3 user input [Recommended Way]

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

When using `input()` for user input in python3, pylint3 throws the warning of `using builtin function - [bad-builtin]`.

When I searched online for this, I found that functions like `map` and `filter`
are in this category because there is a better, recommended way (For comprehensions) for achieving the same results.

So what is the recommended way for this???

PS:
Why doesn't this appear bad to pylint??

```
mes = '\n'.join(iter(input, "###"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any error about `input()` (and it's indeed the right way) with an up-to-date pylint (1.5.5).

As for your second example, what would you expect it to complain about?